# How to remove custom run commands in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I use Notepad++ and to speed up the development of my program I added a keyboard shortcut to the Run menu. This of course took a few tries to get right and now I have multiple entries on the list which read

```
Compile     Ctrl+Shift+S
```

Most of which don't work due to failed attempts. Is there any way to remove the extra commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under `Settings` go to the `Shortcut Mapper`. You should see a tab for `run commands`. Right-Click `delete` to remove the undesirable run command.

More documentation about formatting run commands can be [found here](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/commands).

Comment: On a side note, is there a way to incorporate the currently opened file into the command?
i.e:
ghc -O2 --make <CURRENT FILE>

Comment: In the Help Documentation it will tell you to use `$(FILE_NAME)` for that

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation that documents `$(FILE_NAME)`. The standalone `chm` file has no such references.

Comment: @Ian I've added a link as requested. Hope this helps!